# Removing a leaflet layer by uncheking one layer in control layers when another is checked

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, mapping, gis

Leaflet control layers has two layers: layer1 and layer2. I wonder if someone could give me a hint in order to remove layer1 from the map by automatically unchecking layer1 when layer2 is checked. I tried the code bellow, but it is not working.

```
layer2.on('loading', function () {
    $('#var')[0].textContent = 'Myvar'
    $('#legend1')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: show')
    $('#legend2')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: hidden')
    //lcontrol.removeLayer(layer1); // This line removes layer1 from control layer (Not my need)
    //map.removeLayer(layer1); // This line does  not do anything. I need to uncheck layer1 and remove it from the map by checking layer2.
});
```

Any help will be very appreciated it.

Comment: `if(map.hasLayer(definedLayer))`

Comment: Did you add them both as base layers? https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/example.html this should happen automatically as you can see in this example.

Comment: @shasha-dev, the layers are overlayers, but I would like them to behave as BaseLayers: by checking layer2 , layer1 is automatically unchecked and removed from the map.